# JasperReports JRXML FiIl subDataSet with data

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm trying to fill subdataset with data. I want to take data from my variable/property, fill dataset and retrieve data from dataset, using  $F{field_name}. It is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can fill the subdataset from main dataset. These are some steps to fill the sub dataset:-

Suppose we have field `field_name` in main data set and now we want to pass to the sub data set-

1. Create a parameter `$P{p_field_name}` and add the default value `$F{field_name}` in main dataset.
2. Then edit the query of sub dataset and create parameter `$P{pm_field_name}` and add the default value `$P{p_field_name}`

Answer (score 0):

From my experience is not possible to fill a subdataset without using a chart or a list component. If that's your case you can see how to use a list in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hl_VyvpaiCo). If you need it for a chart is like [this](http://diethardsteiner.blogspot.com.es/2011/11/jaspersoft-ireport-how-to-pass.html)

Otherwise use a subreport and passing your $F{field_name} as datasource, it is explained [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/524953/how-fill-subdataset-jrdatasource)